# What is Container for zend-expressive symfony console command

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, console, symfony-console, mezzio

I'm currently trying to integrate this library

https://www.xtreamwayz.com/blog/2016-02-07-zend-expressive-console-cli-commands

It seems it requires

```
$container = require __DIR__ . '/config/container.php';
```

Can anyone help me out which file it needs to be pointed? And what it looks like>?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your zend-expressive project yet? the container would be the dependency injection container you chose for your project.

you can use the skeleton installer https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-skeleton to configure your project and create the `/config/container.php` file

Comment: The link you have given me, in that, `https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-skeleton/blob/master/config/autoload/dependencies.global.php` is this the container.php?

Comment: it didn't sound like you had a zend-expressive application set up. if you follow those instructions and run the installer `composer create-project zendframework/zend-expressive-skeleton <your_test_app_name>` .... you'll see that the /config/container.php file gets created. then you'd be able to integrate https://www.xtreamwayz.com/blog/2016-02-07-zend-expressive-console-cli-commands

Comment: I'm using zend framework 3 with doctrine orm. That's why I'm being confused.

Comment: Zend Expressive has nothing to do With Zend Framework... It's an middleware based microframework.

Comment: the library you referenced https://www.xtreamwayz.com/blog/2016-02-07-zend-expressive-console-cli-commands is for zend expressive. for creating console commands in zend 3, try https://zendframework.github.io/zend-console/intro/